# Rails/Rspec: uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

When I run `bundle exec rake spec` I keep running into this error: `uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)`

Here is my gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
end

group :development, :test  do
  gem "debugger-ruby_core_source", "~> 1.2.2"
  gem 'debugger' 
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails' 
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'spork-rails', "~> 3.2"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 0.9"
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara' 
  gem 'guard-rspec' 
  gem 'launchy'
  gem "shoulda-matchers", "~> 2.0"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  gem "rspec-sidekiq"
end
```

I can't figure out why this is happening...

Answer (score 0):

If this is your complete

> gemfile

content than I think adding this should solve the problem

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
```

You are getting

> uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)

because you have not added rails to gemfile

Comment: The gemfile I posted was a portion of my gemfile, not the entire file